# android font size difference on tablet

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.4-kitkat

I have two Nexus 7 tab's one on Jelly Bean(4.2) another on KitKat. The text area size defined in dp looks good on KitKat tab but the text gets braked on Jelly Bean tab.
Both are of same model tabs, density, dimension are all same...

any info on this ?

Thank you

Comment: may be google have decreased the font size in kitkat !!

Comment: A screenshot comparison would be nice. "Braked" [sic] is pretty vague. I'm experiencing something similar on my tabs between KitKat and other releases.

Comment: I no longer have jelly bean on my Tab, so cannot share the screenshot comparison. We have Hardware/Software rendering in Android, i believe software rendering was updated. In my case "12sp" was rendered slightly bigger in 4.2 Tab than in 4.4 Tab.